# llblgen AND-OR operators presendence AND-OR

Tags: c#, sql, llblgenpro

I want to generate the llblgen form of sql statement below

```
select * from sometable where

c1=4 AND (  c2 <> 'true' OR c2 IS NULL )
```

But I can't get the exact filter option  operator `AND` has presendence over opeator `OR` so
I'm confused.

Comment: What specifically is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use parenthesis in your PredicateExpression. You also can use separate Predicates and mix them as you want.

This is the relevant info about this in the LLBLGenPro Documentation: [Constructing Predicate Expressions](http://llblgen.com/documentation/3.5/LLBLGen%20Pro%20RTF/hh_goto.htm#Using%20the%20generated%20code/Adapter/Filtering%20and%20Sorting/gencode_filteringpredicateclasses_adapter.htm#constructingpredicateexpressions)